# Django-pipeline not serving files in development mode

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-pipeline

I'm trying to compile static with [django-pipeline](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), but can't manage to serve static in **dev** mode. Since I'm not a Django developer, I may be wrong how Django serves static files itself. Here's my project structure:

- **project** (project itself)

  - project (settings, global urls config, etc.)
  - **app** (main and the only app)

    - **static** (app-based static files, namespaced via **app name** folder)
  - **static** (shared static, that's not linked to specific app)

    - css

      - app.styl
  - **public**

    - media
    - **static** (not used in dev env; only for production: should be served with nginx, auto-generated via collectstatic)

As I'm using shared static, I've specified `STATICFILES_DIRS` directive to allow Django **dev** server and `collectstatic` command to find shared static:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

Here's my `settings.py`:

```
# for production, should be served via nginx
STATIC_ROOT= os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'public/static/')
# prefix for static app
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# also django-pipeline config
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'pipeline.finders.PipelineFinder',
)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'pipeline.storage.PipelineCachedStorage'

PIPELINE = {
    'PIPELINE_ENABLED': True,
    'COMPILERS': (
        'pipeline.compilers.stylus.StylusCompiler',
    ),
    'STYLESHEETS': {
        'app': {
            'source_filenames': (
              'css/app.styl',
            ),
            'output_filename': 'css/app.css',
        },
    },
}
```

In my template I've specified CSS-group:

```
  {% load pipeline %}
  {% stylesheet 'app' %}
</head>
```

As a result, such HTML is generated:

```
  <link href="/static/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

But `/static/css/app.css` returns 404.

If I run `collectstatic`, `public/static/css/app.css` is built. But as I understand Django logic, it's used only for apache/nginx-based production serving and not in **dev** one. In **dev** mode static is served via internal Django server with some middleware django-pipeline hooks.

What I'm doing wrong? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

**UPD:** I've added `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` to global urlpatterns, however can't understand it's why it's recommended — STATIC_ROOT is used only for production with external proxy-server and not with Django itself. Or not?

Comment: If I set `'PIPELINE_ENABLED': False,` Django is collecting static automatically everytime I hit HTTP-request in dev-mode. Is it OK?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For everyone, fighting with the same problem. Just remove `'PIPELINE_ENABLED': True,` away from django-pipeline config. After this, django-pipeline will re-compile static for each request in dev mode.

And before deployment, just run `collectstatic` and set `DEBUG=False`, as it's mentioned in docs. After this pipeline will stop re-compiling files for each request, load minified assets in templates and you'll be able to serve static from `STATIC_ROOT` with any third-part proxy-server like NGINX.

Comment: FYI, the django-pipeline docs state that PIPELINE_ENABLED defaults to "not settings.DEBUG" so it really isn't necessary to set it as long as you're toggling DEBUG.

Answer (score 0):

Original answer of question's author is great, but it seems to me that you don't need to do that manually. You can have this switch with a single `if` `else` conditional control.